# no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a C++ newbie.I tried out my first program here.To my eyes this program is correct.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class mystruct
{
    private:
        int m_a;
        float m_b;

    public:
        mystruct(int x, float y)
        {
                m_a = x;
                m_b = y;
        }

};


int main()
{

        mystruct m = mystruct(5,3.14);

        cout << "my structure " << m << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

However I am getting sooo many errors.Can't figure out why?

```
cout.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
cout.cpp:26:29: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]((* & std::cout), ((const char*)"my structure ")) << m’
cout.cpp:26:29: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:110:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:110:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&) {aka std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)}’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:119:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:119:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)}’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:129:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:129:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:167:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:167:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘long int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:171:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:171:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘long unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:175:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:175:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘bool’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:93:5: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:93:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘short int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:182:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:182:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘short unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:107:5: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:107:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:193:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:193:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:202:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:202:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘long long int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:206:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:206:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘long long unsigned int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:211:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:211:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘double’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:215:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:215:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘float’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:223:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:223:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘long double’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:227:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:227:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘const void*’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:121:5: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:121:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘mystruct’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char>*}’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2693:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:451:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:456:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, char)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:462:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, char)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:468:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, signed char)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:473:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:493:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const _CharT*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:323:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:510:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:523:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const signed char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:528:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const unsigned char*)
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't know how you want your structure printed.  You need to tell it by giving it a function called operator<< that takes an ostream and your type as parameters.  Only then will it know how you want your structure printed.  http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?438624-Printing-user-defined-type-by-cout

Comment: What happens if mystruct has a cast converter to string? Does it still need a << overloading?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to overload operator `<<` for `mystruct` class

Something like :-

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const mystruct& m)
{
    os << m.m_a <<" " << m.m_b << endl;
    return os ;
}
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/cKi8TI)

Comment: Why it has to be a friend function? It can be a member function right? I tried without friend, but get many error messages (First one is: error: 'std::ostream& mystruct::operator<<(std::ostream&, const mystruct&)' must take exactly one argument|)

Comment: @Rajesh It's because the reference to the ostream object has to be the first parameter. The same goes for the stream insertion operator as well. Since they take the user-defined object as the second parameter they must be implemented as a non-member function. They are usually implemented as friend functions because it allows them to access private attributes of a user-defined type, which is sometimes the only way to access them, if the user-defined type has not exposed them through getters.

Answer (score 8):

There's only one error:

> cout.cpp:26:29: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits]((* & std::cout), ((const char*)"my structure ")) << m’

This means that the compiler couldn't find a matching overload for `operator<<`. The rest of the output is the compiler listing `operator<<` overloads that didn't match. The third line actually says this:

> cout.cpp:26:29: note: candidates are:

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, the standard library provided operator does not know what to do with your user defined type `mystruct`. It only works for predefined data types. To be able to use it for your own data type, You need to overload `operator <<` to take your user defined data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can just get:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Mystruct
{
    private:
        int m_a;
        float m_b;

    public:
        //get the value
        int m_getA() {return m_a;} //get the value m_a
        float m_getB() {return m_b;} //get the value m_b

        //set
        void mystruct(int x, float y)
        {
            m_a = x; //set m_a
            m_b = y; //set m_b
        }
};


int main()
{

        Mystruct m;
        m.mystruct(5, 3.14);

        cout << "my structure m(" 
             << m.m_getA() << ","  //use the method to get m_a
             << m.m_getB() << ")"  //use the method to get m_b
             << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to create an object file and use it to get the result

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Mystruct
{
    private:
        int m_a;
        float m_b;

    public:
        mystruct(int x, float y)
        {
                m_a = x;
                m_b = y;
        }

};


int main()
{
    Mystruct objectname; //creating the object file of the class;
    float variable = objectname.mystruct(5,3.14);

    cout << "my structure " << variable << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Object is a collection of methods and variables.You can't print the variables in object by just **cout** operation . if you want to show the things inside the object you have to declare either a getter or a display text method in class.

ex

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class mystruct

{
private:
    int m_a;
    float m_b;

public:
    mystruct(int x, float y)
    {
            m_a = x;
            m_b = y;
    }
    public:
    void getm_aAndm_b()
    {
        cout<<m_a<<endl;
        cout<<m_b<<endl;
    }



};

int main()
{

    mystruct m = mystruct(5,3.14);

    cout << "my structure " << endl;
    m.getm_aAndm_b();
    return 0;
```

}

Not that this is just a one way of doing it

Comment: you can print if you provide the right overload and the right definition of the `<<` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But i believe for the better programming practice and pure object orientation .We should always respect to the rules declared by the "smalltalk" . Then you see the encapsulation of the code is well protected

Comment: I believe it is way more elegant to overload the << operator. :)