# How to store value in std::variant when using a class as a datatype?

Tags: c++, variant

I created a class and used the class as my data type for std::variant. But when I store value I cannot access it as it shows some error.

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Random
{
    public:
        int rand_number;
        float rand_dec;
};

int main(){
    Random random;
    random.rand_number=1;
    random.rand_dec=2.1;
    
    std::variant<Random,std::string> input{ "Hello" };
    
    auto PrintVisitor = [](const auto& t) { std::cout << t << "\n"; };
    std::visit(PrintVisitor, input);}
```

So,I want to know how to access the value when I use a class because there is no problem when I use default data types?

The error was too large so I am posting the important parts

```
 19 52  C:\Users\Khusi\Documents\CPP\test2.cpp  [Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'const Random')
```

Comment: Please post the exact error and where it occurs. It's much easier not guessing.

Comment: As the error states, you have not defined an `operator<<` overload for `Random`.

Comment: @0x5453 can you please tell me how to do that? I am pretty new to this and I dont know how tto do stuff.

Comment: @SHIVANSHUSAHOO [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22588163/3282436) question has some examples.

Comment: @0x5453 Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

When visiting your variable `input`, which accepts only two types: your class `Random` and `std::string`, the function `PrintVisitor` does one operation for every member of your variable: `std::cout << t << "\n";`. So the class std::string has an overload output operator but your class doesn't. You need to implement it.

There you are an example of overloading the output operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks for the help