# Why does " error: no match for 'operator<<' " occur when searching for the iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector, cout, libstdc++

I am looking for the positions of an element using `find();` method, but for some reason it conflicts whit the `cout<<` and I don't understand why.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, busquedas, num,
    vas=0, pet=0;
    vector <int> arreglo;

    cin>>n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin>> num;
        arreglo.push_back(num);
    }
    cin>>busquedas;
    for(int i = 0; i < busquedas; i++){
        cin>>num;
        std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find(arreglo.begin(), arreglo.end(), num);  
        cout<<it; //Here the error occurs
    }
    return 0; }
```

Also I have tried to change the `iterator` to the `auto` type and it shows the same error.

Comment: What do you expect `cout<<it` to print?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588163/no-match-for-operator-in-stdoperator might be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that the `<<` operator is not supported for the iterator type with `std::cout`. Try doing this if you want to see the distance of the iterator from the beginning of the vector.

```
std::cout << std::distance(arreglo.begin(), it) << std::endl;
```

Or this if you want the value in the array the iterator points to (thanks @Slava for the idea of the segfault avoidance).

```
if (it != arreglo.end())
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

Comment: You probably should mention that OP has to check that `it` is not equal to `end()` before dereferencing.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you cannot print iterator << operator is not overloaded for that.

You can either print the value at `it - vec.begin()` it will print the index of your element in Vector

You also should check `it != vec.end()`.