# regarding error in getting output from cout

Tags: c++, linked-list, cout

Error:

> no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'node')

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;

public:
    Node(int data1)
    {
        data = data1;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    Node *rootNode = new Node(arr[0]);
    cout << rootNode;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting to get the linked list.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588163/no-match-for-operator-in-stdoperator

Comment: The code shown is not consistent with the error message.  Please provide a [mcve] and the real error message.

Comment: You seem to have skipped some chapters in your book, a few steps in the tutorial you follow, or a few lectures in your class. Please don't do that. And if you don't have a book, then please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and don't skip anything. Learning by guessing seldom works out well, and it's almost impossible with C++.

Comment: You need to overload operator << for Node class.

Comment: A side note: in modern C++ is it better to avoid raw pointers and manual allocations/deallocations. Instead you can use smart pointers (or even better if applicable - the standard containers). In the code you posted you have a memory leak since `rootNode` is `new`ed but not `delete`ed.

Comment: your code compiles and produces expected output https://godbolt.org/z/Yox9rrGds.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm expecting to get the linked list

Why would you expect that? How do you think `operator<<` will know how you want your custom `Node` class to be printed out?

The code you have shown compiles and runs, but the output is simply the memory address of the `Node` object, not the `data` value it holds. That is because there is an existing `operator<<` that prints raw pointers.

For what you want, you have to tell the operator how you want a `Node` to be printed. You do that by overloading `operator<<`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next = nullptr;

public:
    Node(int data1) : data(data1) { }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Node &node)
    {
        os << node.data;
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    Node *rootNode = new Node(arr[0]);
    cout << *rootNode;
    delete rootNode;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/lL6FuE)

If you want to print a whole list, you are best off wrapping the `Node` list inside another class, and then overloading `operator<<` for that class, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class List
{
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node *next = nullptr;

        Node(int data1) : data(data1) { }
    };

    Node *head, *tail;

public:
    List() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) { }
    List(const List&) = delete;
    List& operator=(const List&) = delete;

    ~List()
    {
        Node *n = head;
        while (n)
        {
            Node *next = n->next;
            delete n;
            n = next; 
        }
    }

    void push_back(int data)
    {
        Node **n = (tail) ? &(tail->next) : &head;
        *n = new Node(data);
        tail = *n;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const List &list)
    {
        Node *n = list.head;
        if (n)
        {
            os << n->data;
            while (n = n->next)
            {
                os << ',' << n->data;
            }
        }
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    List list;
    for(int elem : arr)
        list.push_back(elem);
    cout << list;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/6g1JQZ)